# AWK - if not in array

Tags: unix, awk, compare, gawk

I have two files separated by tabs. Comparing files by the first field, I need to print the line where the field does not match. But the line to be printed is from the file (file1)

File1:

```
adu adu noun    singular    n/a n/a nominative
aduink  adu noun    plural  1pl n/a nominative
adum    adu noun    singular    1s  n/a nominative
```

File2:

```
adu adu noun    singular    n/a n/a nominative
aduink  adu noun    plural  1pl n/a nominative
xxadum  adu noun    singular    1s  n/a nominative
```

Desired output:

```
adum    adu noun    singular    1s  n/a nominative
```

What I'm thinking:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

But I need to print, the line from file (file1) not from file (file2). And I can not change the order to process files

Comment: Your `FNR==NR` expression gets run on the first file listed after the awk script, in this case `file1`. That means that your subsequent expression, `!($1 in a)`, is evaluated against lines in `file2`.  If you want to store `$1` of `file2` in the array and then compare lines of `file1` against the array, simply swap the order of the files on your awk command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't change the files order (that is more simple), but you with the same order, you can do that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$0; next }
     { delete a[$1] }
     END{ for (x in a) print a[x] }' file1 file2
```

The idea is to delete all items at index `$1` when the second file is processed. Then at the end, you only need to print the remaining items.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you interchange the files in the argument that you are passing to `awk`,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1
                                          |     |
                                         arg1  arg2
```

Comment: No need for `=$0`, it's not used and just sucking up memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the file order when awk is called, just change it inside awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{t=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]; ARGV[2]=t} FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

That way you don't have to store either file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but here is a simpler way to do this

```
$ join -v1 file1 file2

adum adu noun singular 1s n/a nominative
```

that is, to suppress joined lines and print the unpaired lines from first file. By default join is by first field.